# AS3 drawing lines, making shorter after that

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

i have a little math/coding problem witch i don`t have any idea how could i do it work in a simple way, so the problem is is need to make a line shorter, with 15

in my program i have :
 http://gyazo.com/aff5ff61fb9ad3ecedde3118d9c0895e

the line takes the center coordinates of both circles and draws from one to another, but i need it to be from the circumference of the circles, so it won`t get inside
the code i`m using is :

```
var  line:Shape = new Shape();
    line.graphics.lineStyle(3,0xFF0000,2);
    line.graphics.moveTo(sx,sy);
    line.graphics.lineTo(fx,fy);
    this.addChild(line);
    arrow2(sx,sy,fx,fy);

    var rline:Shape = new Shape();
    rline.graphics.lineStyle(3,0xFF0000,2);
    rline.graphics.moveTo(fx,fy);
    rline.graphics.lineTo(xa,ya);
    this.addChild(rline);

    var rline2:Shape = new Shape();
    rline2.graphics.lineStyle(3,0xFF0000,2);
    rline2.graphics.moveTo(fx,fy);
    rline2.graphics.lineTo(xb,yb);
    this.addChild(rline2);
```

the rline and rline2 function is for the arrow lines, now my question is how do i make it shorter not depending on it direction so it will not overlap the circle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use vectors to solve your problem; they're pretty easy to get the hang of, and pretty much indispensable for things like game dev or what you're trying to do. You can get an overview here: http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/vectors.html or by searching "vector math" in google

So first step is to get a vector from one circle to another (pretty much what you've done):

```
var vector:Point = new Point( circle2.x - circle1.x, circle2.y - circle1.y );
var length:Number = vector.length; // store the length of the vector for later
```

This is the equivalent of saying *"if you start at `circle1` and move along `vector`, you'll arrive at `circle2`"*

Next thing we're going to do is normalise it; all this does is set the length to `1` - the direction is unchanged - this makes it easier to work with for what you're looking to do. A vector with length `1.0` is called a *unit vector*:

```
vector.normalize( 1.0 ); // you can pass any length you like, but for this example, we'll stick with 1.0
```

Now, to draw a line from one circle to another, but starting from the outside, we simply find the start and the end points. The starting point is simple the position of `circle1` plus `vector` (normalised to unit length) multiplied by the radius of `circle1`:

```
var sx:Number = circle1.x + vector.x * circle1.radius; // or circle1.width * 0.5 if you don't store the radius
var sy:Number = circle1.y + vector.y * circle1.radius;
```

The ending point can be found by starting at our start point, and continuing along our `vector` for a distance equal to the distance between the two circles (minus their radii). The `length` value that we created earlier is the distance between your two circles, from one center point to another, so we can use that to get the distance minus the radii:

```
var dist:Number = length - ( circle1.radius + circle2.radius ); // or circle1.width * 0.5 etc
```

And so the end point:

```
var ex:Number = sx + vector.x * dist;
var ey:Number = sy + vector.y * dist;
```

And to draw the line between them:

```
var line:Shape = new Shape;
line.graphics.lineStyle( 1.0, 0x000000 );
line.graphics.moveTo( sx, sy );
line.graphics.lineTo( ex, ey );
this.addChild( line )
```